# ForEach on Stream with index

Tags: kotlin

is it possible to use somehow foreach method on `Stream<T>` with index?

Like `forEachIndexed {index, value -> }` on `List<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to keep working with Java's `Streams` you can use: [asSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/java.util.stream.-stream/as-sequence.html)

And your code becomes:

`stream.asSequence().forEachIndexed {...}`